Will applying sealant regularly extend the life of a 12 year old vehicle?
I'm driving a 2012 Chevy Cruze with only 160 000 kilometers on it, and in pretty good shape rust wise, as we've been doing undercoating consistently every year. However, it does have quite a few imperfections in the paint, scratches, and one small ding. I haven't taken a picture of the ding, but there is a black area that's exposed. Not sure what the black area actually is.
I don't have a reasonable idea of how much longer this vehicle is going to last, and we're in the process of saving for our next vehicle. For various reasons we have a hard time detailing the vehicle ourselves, so it's costing us about 400/year to have this done for us. Once in the spring, and once in the fall.
I guess I'm more specifically looking at the long-term health of the car. I largely expect the car to die before we get rid of it, it's just a question of whether detailing it will actually add any longevity given the already existing imperfections. I just don't really know the answer to that question. But if I'm detailing it largely for appearance sake, then that's a different equation.
So does it make more sense to just start pocketing the money we're spending on having it detailed, or will detailing it actually add longevity / value?

While I feel your plight, I'm thinking this question is just going to garner opinions and not get any real answers. Bottom line is, is it worth it to you. Putting money towards detailing or new car is something only you can answer.

I guess I'm more specifically looking at the long-term health of the car. I largely expect the car to die before we get rid of it, it's just a question of whether detailing it will actually add any longevity given the already existing imperfections. I just don't really know the answer to that question. But if I'm detailing it largely for appearance sake, then that's a different equation.
